# Show this set is a base for some topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

Given $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a \neq 0$ define, 
$$S(a,b)=\{an+b : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
Then $\mathscr{B}=\{S(a.b) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \  \{0\}, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a base for some topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$.

My work:  We need to show that for every $x \in S(a,b) \cap S(c,d)$ there exists another base element $S(e,f)$ such that $x \in S(e,f)$.

So far I've noted the following, 
$$S(a,b)=\{x : x \equiv b(mod \,a)\}$$
$$S(c,d)=\{y : y \equiv d(mod \,c)\}$$ 
now I am trying to find what the elements of the intersection of these sets are, through basically testing a couple examples it looks to be the set $S(ac, b+d)=\{(ac)n+(b+d) : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Now is where I need help, I can't find a nice way to show that this set is in fact the intersection.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: This is Furstenberg's topology, used in his topological proof of the infinitude of primes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes

Comment: Oh.. wow that's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: In all of your examples were $a$ and $c$ relatively prime?

Comment: Ohh yeah I think they may have been.  I can't remember everything I tried but all the ones I can are relatively prime.

Comment: Where's my friend, the empty set?  What's $S(2,0)\cap S(2,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $S(a,b)\cap S(c,d)$ is not empty, and let $x\in S(a,b)\cap S(c,d)$.

Then show $S(\operatorname{lcm}(a,c),x)\subseteq S(a,b)\cap S(c,d)$.

It's actually equal, although you don't really need equality.

Comment: Is the fact that the intersection can be empty for certain values of $a$ and $b$ a problem for it being a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Of course, but if the intersection is empty, we don't care - that is also an (empty) union of $S(a,b)$ sets. @JustinStevenson